# mapping reduction from $A_i=\{x|i \in W_x\}$ to $A_j=\{x|j \in W_x\}$

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions

If $$ A_n = \{ x | n \in W_x\}  \ where \ W_x \ is \ domain \ of  \ M_x $$
how can I show that 
$$ \forall i,j \ \ \ A_i \le_M A_j  $$

Answer (score 1):

The language $A_i$ consists of all Turing machines which halt on input "$i$".

Suppose I have an oracle which, given a Turing machine, can tell me whether it halts on the input $j$. Using this oracle, I want to decide, given a Turing machine, whether it halts on the input $i$. Can you think of a way of doing this?